# Answering questions for a ban to be lifted

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I was banned from asking questions in Stack Overflow. so I read the guide. I looked at many of my questions and really just said "... yeah there's no way to fix that". Then I saw that I should contribute positively to the community with answers to have the ban lifted.

However, do answers have to be upvoted in order for ban to be lifted?

I have been answering questions but they're all sitting at 0 points. I checked them before submitting them to make sure they're right, but other people had answers which were selected first.

Comment: Try answering new question with no previous answers, or search through all the unanswered questions

Comment: The specifics around the ban algorithm are secret. People have guesses, but I've not heard anything around that, in particular.

Comment: Try to improve your existing posts to get rid of the downvotes.

Answer (score 9):

**Don't delete your own questions.**

When I checked a little while ago, you had only one question with a negative score (-7). Checking again just now, that question has disappeared. Did you delete it? More to the point, deleting a lot of your own questions seems to be one of the things that can trigger the automatic question ban. If you've deleted more than a few, you should consider improving the questions and undeleting them.

**Answers get upvoted when they're helpful.**

I took a look at some of the zero score answers you've posted, and I notice that many of them are very brief and not very clear. For example, compare your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15736095/643383) to the others for that question, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15736055/643383). While it's true that it's not a great question in the first place, it's also apparent that you spent about 15 seconds writing an answer whereas the other respondents made a much greater effort to be helpful.

Similarly, compare [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10052188/643383) to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10052246/643383) to *[jQuery detect hover over left or right of a single div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10052119/643383)*. Yours is a one-liner without an example; the accepted answer has both example code and a link to a demo.

Brief answers can be okay if they provide a clear answer, and a brief answer is better than a needlessly wordy one. But an upvote indicates that the answer is "helpful," and a thorough, clearly explained answer is more likely to garner upvotes than a one-liner.