# Do migrated posts affect question/answer bans?

Tags: discussion, migration, post-ban

Suppose a user is question or answer banned from a certain site. And suppose a question was migrated from another site to the one where the user was banned. And suppose the user's answer from the other site *on someone else's question* was highly upvoted on the destination site.

Do the upvotes on the user's answer to the migrated question count toward removing a question or answer ban?

Comment: "question was migrated from..." is impossible, see [Block migration if user is suspended/question-blocked at destination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination)

Comment: @gnat: I belive that would be true if the user had asked the question. I wonder if it is true if someone else had asked the question, and the user answered it. I edited my question to bring it in line with this variation.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174469/answering-questions-for-a-ban-to-be-lifted